# Subdomain proxy pass all pointing to single server

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy, tomcat

I have 2 applications hosted on a single apache tomcat on port 8080
>

> - `http://mydomain.com:8080/application1`
> - `http://mydomain.com:8080/application2`

I would like to run an apache proxy in front of BOTH of them with the following behaviour
>

> - `http://mydomain.com/* (apache2) -> http://mydomain.com:8080/application1/* (tomcat)`
> - `http://subdomain.mydomain.com/* (apache2) -> http://mydomain.com:8080/application2/* (tomcat)`

The best I have got right now is 2 machines with different IPs and routing the domain and subdomains correspondingly.

Ideally I want the apache proxy and the 2 apps to be on the SAME machine...

Can anyone with kick arse DEVOps skills assist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to @Jon Lin answer, consider using `ProxyPassReverse` also, just in case your app do any redirects. It makes Apache correct URL's on responses (More about [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)). It will look like that:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.mydomain.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/application1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/application1/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/application1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/application1/
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: does it work if we keep *:80 but adding a specific subdomain before the * rule?

Comment: Adding the subdomain before the rule breaks it for me

Answer (score 4):

In the virtualhost config for **mydomain.com** (apache), you need

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com:8080/application1/$1
```

In the virtualhost config for **subdomain.mydomain.com** (apache), you nede

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com:8080/application2/$1
```

Both config files should be on the same machine, and even the same file. See [VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for some examples on how this is setup.